# IsEnable Property not working inside ListView Item xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my listview:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ContentView 
                BackgroundColor="White">
                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding PullSheetId}" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    IsVisible="False"/>
                <controls:CheckBox 
                    Checked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableShipBtn}" 
                    Scale=".8"/>
                <!--<Label 
                    Text="{Binding KitSKU}" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    FontSize="Small" 
                    TextColor="Black"/>-->
                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding SKU}" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    FontSize="Small" 
                    TextColor="{Binding ItemColor}"/>
                <Label 
                    Text="{Binding ReqPackQty}" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    FontSize="Small" 
                    TextColor="Black"/>
            </ContentView>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

`IsEnabled` property not working while it is working on `IsVisible`.
How to solve this?

Comment: What is the `ItemsSource`? What does the object in there look like? Of which object is the `IsEnableShipBtn` a member? We need some more code to get to the bottom of this

Comment: Also, what is controls:CheckBox? Your implementation of a custom checkboox? Is the Enabled property correctly bindable?

Comment: controls:Checkbox is a Form CheckBox,and Yes my Binding is correct but its not working with only IsEnabled,its working fine on IsVisible

Comment: Just help me with two things, How have you defined the BindableProperty for IsEnabled & is `IsEnableShipBtn` a part of your listview's binding model

Comment: Both are same,I want to bind this checkbox and button same